# SASS mixin doesn't get imported in LINUX but does in my exact same WINDOWS setup

Tags: linux, git, sass, scss-mixins

I have a windows dev environment where there is a project based on SASS, everything works fine but, the same environment on LINUX doesn't let me import a mixin, I've tried installing and un-installing sass from the command line but nothing works.

The sass `@use` statement

> `@use 'layout' as *;`

_layout.scss has mixins and variables

> `@mixin button($color: null, $bg-color: null, $font-size: null) {...}`

When I run `sass --watch --style compressed sass/global/account.scss:css/global/account.min.css` I get this error

> Change detected to: sass/global/account.scss
> ***error sass/global/account.scss (Line 6: Undefined mixin 'button'.)***

The directory structure and everything is fine cuz *THIS WORKS* on the windows environment, and both are cloned from the same repo.

Comment: What version of Sass are you using on each system?  Are all the files all lowercase on both systems?

Comment: @bk2204 yessir, everything is exactly the same, both are clones of the same repo.